# Replace one word with another without shifting the text in beamer

Tags: beamer

So in my presentation I want to replace a term in the equation with another term, I know that I can do this with \only but then there will be a small shift of the entire equation. Basically I want to know if there is some way to have the \visible tool where you fix a certain space but then without invisibility but with replacement for a different term instead.

Comment: you can use `\makebox[2cm]{yes}` and `\makebox[2cm]{no}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of the `calc` package and its `\widthof` command you can measure the width of the wider trm and place the narrower term in a `\makebox` of the before measured width:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{equation}
A + \only<1>{\makebox[\widthof{$DDDD$}]{$B$}}\only<2>{DDDD} = C
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. There seems to be something wrong with this package, because it somehow gives an error if I write math with or without dollar signs in the second part of the makebox function (it works properly if I don't use maths).

Comment: @RubenLier: I don't seem to be able to reproduce this. Could you please give na example?

Comment: Well copying your thing already goes wrong for me when I compile it in Overleaf